# Why does my code not work when using ist over workbook-boundaries but work when using it in the same Workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with two worksheets.

The first sheet contains a list of email adresses.
The second sheet contains a list of email adresses of which some match the ones in first sheet and some may not

I added a button and some code (see below). When i hit the button excel looks in sheet2 and compares it with the email addresses in sheet1 ... if it finds equal email-addresses it adds the found email address & the "allowed"-state behind the existing address in sheet1.

This is working fine:

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call lookup
    End Sub


    Sub lookup()
    Dim TotalRows As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long

    'Copy lookup values from sheet1 to sheet3

    Sheets("Tabelle1").Select
    TotalRows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    For i = 1 To TotalRows
    'Search for the value on sheet2
    Set rng = Sheets("Tabelle2").UsedRange.Find(Cells(i, 1).Value)
    'If it is found put its value on the destination sheet
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        Cells(i, 2).Value = rng.Value
        Cells(i, 3).Value = "Allowed"
    End If
    Next
    End Sub
```

But now I want to have the button in one "trigger.xlsm"-file and the data is in two different workbooks. ...so i have one button to copy the compare data from workbook2 to sheet2 in workbook1.... this works well!

But the rest of the code that compares and writes the equal mail-addresses in workbook1 - sheet1 does not... every line is filled with "allowed"-state.

I tried with this code which gives the above result:

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\DEJP0050\Documents\testvon.xlsx"
    Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\DEJP0050\Documents\testnach.xlsm"

    Workbooks("testvon.xlsx").Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("A:A").Copy _
    Workbooks("testnach.xlsm").Sheets("Tabelle2").Range("A:A")



    Workbooks("testvon.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=True
    Workbooks("testnach.xlsm").Close SaveChanges:=True

    End Sub



    Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()



    Call lookup



    End Sub

    Sub lookup()

    Dim TotalRows As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim wb1 As Excel.Workbook
    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\DEJP0050\Documents\testnach.xlsx")
    Dim ws11 As Worksheet
    Set ws11 = wb1.Sheets("Tabelle1")
    Dim ws12 As Worksheet
    Set ws12 = wb1.Sheets("Tabelle2")
    'Copy lookup values from sheet1 to sheet3

    'ws11.Select
    TotalRows = ws11.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    'Range("A1:A" & TotalRows).Copy 
    Destination:=Sheets("Tabelle3").Range("A1")

    'Go to the destination sheet
    'Sheets("Tabelle3").Select

     For i = 1 To TotalRows
    'Search for the value on sheet2
     Set rng = ws12.UsedRange.Find(Cells(i, 1).Value)
    'If it is found put its value on the destination sheet
     If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        ws11.Cells(i, 2).Value = rng.Value
        'Cells(i, 2).Value = "Allowed"
        ws11.Cells(i, 3).Value = "Allowed"
     End If
     Next

     Workbooks("testnach.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=True

     End Sub
```

Why does it work when the button is within the same workbook, but doesnt work when the button is in another workbook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need to change

```
Sheets("Tabelle1").Select
```

to

```
activeworkbook.Sheets("Tabelle1").Select
```

AND

```
TotalRows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

to

```
TotalRows = activeworkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

AND

```
Set rng = Sheets("Tabelle2").UsedRange.Find(Cells(i, 1).Value)
```

to

```
Set rng = activeworkbook.Sheets("Tabelle2").UsedRange.Find(activeworkbook.Sheets("Tabelle2").Cells(i, 1).Value)
```

Comment: This is a bit better because now the email addresses are copied to the second colums of sheet 1, until now this didn´t work.... but the problem is nearly the same, all emails of sheet 2 are copied to sheet one, even though they are not in the sheet 1. ...the comparison of equality does not work... and the "allowed" value is set to every entry, not only the matching ones